# Constraint Layout hide View with chain weight

Tags: android, visibility, android-constraintlayout, constraint-layout-chains

Hy,

I want to have 2 Views equally spread the screen width in a ConstraintLayout.
Used chains and weight to achieve that.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonLeft"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:text="Left"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guidelineLeft"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonRight"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonRight"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:text="Right"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/buttonLeft"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guidelineRight"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"/>
```

Now i want to hide the right View and the left to grow to fill the width.

I thought this could work out of the box because of the [visiblity behaviour](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#VisibilityBehavior)

But as the left button has a constraint on the right one, it does not grow.

Any ideas how to solve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hiding the right view works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLeft"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:text="Left"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonRight"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonRight"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:text="Right"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/buttonLeft"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guidelineRight"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guidelineRight"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="70dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

... but hiding the left view doesn't. I filed a bug here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=234897

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. but if i use your proposed layout, the left view does not grow when the right one is hidden. at least the layout editor does not show it. see [here](https://imgur.com/a/TpKD4)